# VBScript get external IP address and telnet it to a device

Tags: vbscript, ip, external, telnet

I have some knowledge about programming and i've searched the web a bit, but i can't seem to find what i need.

This is the deal, i have a device that uses an ethernet module for communication from Lantronix called Xport.

Now, that device can be configured through a web browser or Telnet.

Among the options their's one called remote IP.

I'm trying to develop a script that can capture my external IP Address, memorize each number from that ip to a variable, then open my device through telnet, access a certain option that he has, and write that IP through sendkeys or something.

By each number i mean 192, number 1, number 9 and number 2, for example.

Another option would be a script that does the same through web browser.

I've already crated some batch files that do some of that, one of the batch files asks for an IP, number by number (i have to write everything, 0's and all, for example 66 writes 066), then open the telnet, insert a password in the device, send several keys until the option i want, enter that option, writes the ip that i've wrote and then exits. But i found that script is not very user friendly.

So i'm looking for a two click file solution.

This is what i've got so far.

First the batch file that i use today.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off

rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

echo Please write the IP address one number at a time, pressing enter after each number

echo Insert first Number

set /p var1=

echo Insert second Number

set /p var2=

echo Insert ... Number

set /p var3=

echo Insert ... Number

set /p var4=

echo Insert ... Number

set /p var5=

echo Insert ... Number

set /p var6=

echo Insert ... Number

set /p var7=

echo Insert ... Number

set /p var8=

echo Insert ... Number

set /p var9=

echo Insert ... Number

set /p var10=

echo Insert ... Number

set /p var11=

echo Insert ... Number

set /p var12=

rem Starts Telnet and enters the device, then inserts the IP

start "" /B telnet.exe address.com 9999

ping -n 1 -w 1 127.0.0.1 > NUL
%SendKeys% "{p}{a}{s}{s}{w}{o}{r}{d}{ENTER}"

%SendKeys% "echo off{ENTER}"

%SendKeys% "echo off{1}{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}"

%SendKeys% "echo off{%var1%}{%var2%}{%var3%}{ENTER}{%var4%}{%var5%}{%var6%}{ENTER}{%var7%}{%var8%}{%var9%}{ENTER}{%var10%}{%var11%}{%var12%}{ENTER}"

%SendKeys% "echo off{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}{ENTER}"

%SendKeys% "echo off{9}{ENTER}"

set /P "=" < NUL
ping -n 1 -w 1 127.0.0.1 > NUL
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"

goto :EOF


@end


// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

If i could get the external IP through a batch file and put each number in a variable, and then mix this bat with that one, it would be a solution too.

I also have some vbs files and i want tu put them together.

First the code to get the external IP (this one i got from here)

```
Option Explicit
Dim objHTTP : Set objHTTP = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXmlHttp")
objHTTP.Open "GET", "http://icanhazip.com", False
objHTTP.Send
Wscript.Echo objHTTP.ResponseText
Set objHTTP  = Nothing
```

Then the code to write variables to a text (but what i want is to write the ip to telnet)

```
Dim Input, filesys, filetxt, getname, path
Input = InputBox("Enter your name") 

Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("DataLog.txt", 8, True)
path = filesys.GetAbsolutePathName("DataLog.txt")
getname = filesys.GetFileName(path)
filetxt.WriteLine input & ", " & ServiceTag
filetxt.close
```

I've tried to mix this two togheter, but it didn't work

```
Option Explicit
Dim objHTTP : Set objHTTP = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXmlHttp")
objHTTP.Open "GET", "http://icanhazip.com", False
objHTTP.Send
Set objHTTP  = Nothing

dim filesys, filetxt, getname, path
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("DataLog.txt", 8, True)
path = filesys.GetAbsolutePathName("DataLog.txt")
getname = filesys.GetFileName(path)
filetxt.WriteLine objHTTP.ResponseText & ", " & ServiceTag
filetxt.Close
```

By the way, one question, what is the servicetag for!?!?!? (well i'll check that one on google, but if someone wants to tell me, i'll be appreciated).

Thank you in advance for all or any help!

**19-08-2014**

Well Matt, i'm almost there but i'm still missing a peace of the puzzle, which is to write the external ip through sendkeys, and for that i tried to just call the variable with the external IP, but it doesn't work, so i need to split it into arrays like you said. i just need to find where to place you're code with mine.

This is my code so far (i hate to have to give four spaces for each code line, there's got to be an easier way to place code here).

```
Option Explicit
Dim objHTTP : Set objHTTP = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXmlHttp")
objHTTP.Open "GET", "http://icanhazip.com", False
objHTTP.Send

On Error Resume Next

Dim WshShell

set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.run "cmd.exe"

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "telnet domain.com 9999"

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "p"

WshShell.SendKeys "a"

WshShell.SendKeys "s"

WshShell.SendKeys "s"

WshShell.SendKeys "w"

WshShell.SendKeys "o"

WshShell.SendKeys "r"

WshShell.SendKeys "d"

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "1"

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

Set objWSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WScript.Sleep 1000

objWSHShell.SendKeys objHTTP.ResponseText

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WScript.Quit 

Set objHTTP  = Nothing
```

So now i just need to put the external ip where i have the line

```
objWSHShell.SendKeys objHTTP.ResponseText
```

which is not working has it should, i mean i can make it write the ip to a text file, and i imagine that it writes one character at a time (or doesn't it?), so if it does, it should write to telnet, but it doesn't, and that's why i need to brake the external IP apart, number by number and adding the dot's (.) whithout the brakets.

Comment: In your final code example you delete the object reference with `Set objHTTP  = Nothing` then you later try to refer to it again with `objHTTP.ResponseText`. If nothing else you need to move your Nothing line to the bottom.

Comment: converted to answer as best i could

Answer (score 0):

In your final code example you delete the object reference with `Set objHTTP  = Nothing` then you later try to refer to it again with `objHTTP.ResponseText`. If nothing else you need to move your `Set objHTTP  = Nothing` line to the bottom.

Guessing you code bite that from someone using it to get information for a Dell system. Since you are just writing it with `Writeline` I don't see it being needed in your code

As for the ip address into variables you could convert the string into a character array and address it that way.

```
Function IPAddressToCharArray(pIpAddress)
    Dim intCounter
    Dim intLen
    Dim singleCharacter
    Dim strFormattedIpAddress
    Dim arrChars()

    ' Remove the periods
    ' strFormattedIpAddress = Replace(pIpAddress,".","")

    ' Set the array length
    intLen = Len(strFormattedIpAddress)-1
    redim arrChars(intLen)

    ' Cycle through the string
    For intCounter = 0 to intLen
        ' Capture the current character.
        arrChars(intCounter)  = Mid(strFormattedIpAddress, intCounter + 1,1)
    Next

    IPAddressToCharArray = arrChars
End Function
```

I dont see a need for this but it would create the array. You could then use a for each object loop to process.

If you wanted to work with this then you just need to put it through a For Each Loop to extract everycharater. If you are using `option explicit` these variables will need to be declared.

```
For Each strSingleCharacter in IPAddressToCharArray(objHTTP.ResponseText)
    WshShell.SendKeys strSingleCharacter
Next
```

Look at [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/automate-telnet-commands-vb-script/) telnet example though there is no need to break up the characters for send keys. Since sendkeys documentation states: "Send one or more keystrokes to the active window as if they were typed at the keyboard. This method is similar to the VB SendKeys method."

For example:
`WshShell.SendKeys "telnet 55.42.58.123 49000"`

Comment: Ok, thank you again for your help Matt. I don't mean to ask for someone to do the code for me, but can someone put a VBS example code to convert the string into characters please? Anyway, of course i'm going to try and search for myself. But after i've converted, how do i issue the telnet? I'll i have to use the sendkeys command? This are questions that i already made and have not bean clarified yet.

Comment: Thank you so much Matt, you're the bomb. I'll try you're code and i'll also try to mix with the one from the link you gave, then i'll feedback the progress here, if everything ok, i'll mark this case as finished.

Comment: If you find my answer useful please mark it as such. If you have other questions feel free to start another one in SO.

Comment: i updated my answer with simple ( and untested ) for each loop

Comment: Matt, i really appreciate your answer, but i'm just not seeing where should i put the loop code, in my code that i updated in my first questions. Do i just need to put the loop code, or do i need the IPAaddressToChar array code, and then your loop code? Please, just grab my updated code in the first question and put your code where it shoud be and place it here. I would really be very appreciated if you could do that for me. Like i said in my first question i have some knowledge of programming, but i'm limited. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Traditionally function are placed and the end of code. I dont know where you want to put the loop code exactly. Wherever you place it will use SendKeys to output the ip address.

Comment: Matt, i finally got it working, i just copy and paste the code you gave me, to split the external IP into arrays and, the loop code. I would like to share the code, so others can also benefit from my question and your knowledge. Can i place the code as an answer here or do i create a question, saying i'm just sharing the code. And finally how can i mark this question as answered? Thank you again Matt.

Comment: You should see a check mark under the answers that you can use. If you can add another answer if you think it helps the question.